# Excel - Array Formula, Countifs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using this formula which works fine:

```
=IF(ROWS(K$62:K62)>SUM(COUNTIFS(accounts_table[§],{"P","B"})),"",INDEX(accounts_table[Account Name],SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(accounts_table[§],{"P","B"},0)),ROW(accounts_table[§])-ROW(INDEX(accounts_table[§],1,1))+1),ROWS($K$62:K62))))
```

However, I need to add another COUNTIFS criteria in the first part of the function as:

```
COUNTIFS(accounts_table[§],{"P","B"},accounts_table[on],"On")
```

If I only make this change, the function doesn't work as expected. I presume I also need to change the second part of the function but can't figure out how. Any help would be much appreciated.

My data is structured as follows:

```
col A   col B    col C
P       on       item1
P       off      item2
B       on       item3
J       on       item4
P       on       item5
B       off      item6
```

So in the above example the array formula should pick item1, item3,item5

Hope it makes sense

Comment: May you provide the data input and output, please?

Comment: This function takes a list, and if the criteria {P,B} are met in adjacent column, then it enters the item in the array and moves on to the next one. Now I want to meet another rule in another column, which is simply having the value "on"

Comment: I have provided example :)

Comment: why not `COUNTIFS(accounts_table[§],"P",accounts_table[on],"On")+COUNTIFS(accounts_table[§],"B",accounts_table[on],"On")` ?